# Facebook logged in user as drupal user

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, facebook-login

I wrote one facebook login module, and I am using facebook php-sdk.

**Here is my code:**

```
function facebook_block_block_view($delta='') {
 $block = array();
 require 'src/facebook.php';
 $appid = variable_get('appid_variable', '');
 $secret = variable_get('secret_variable', '');
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $appid,
    'secret' => $secret,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $new_user = array(
    'name' => $user_profile['name'],
//  'pass' => 'Password',
    'mail' => $user_profile['email'],
    'signature_format' => 'full_html',
    'status' => 1,
    'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
    'init' => 'Email',
    'roles' => 'Roles',
);
$account= user_save(NULL, $new_user);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}


$output='<a href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'"> Login with facebook</a>';
   switch($delta) {
    case 'facebook_login' :
     $block['content'] = $output;
     break;
   }

  return $block;
}
```

Now I can get user's email and name, and I also can save user's information. But how can I let the facebook user become drupal user, that the user can work as drupal globle user?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the drupal function [user_authenticate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_authenticate/7) to log in the user.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_authenticate/7